# Band image recognition with python

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I have the following physical "band" with two lines of small buttons with colors (they vary in **color** and **shape**). I know how all the buttons look beforehand. I don't have a picture, but in text it looks like:

```
(red circle)    (green square)  (blue circle)
(green square)  (green square)  (red circle)
```

I need to be able to take a picture of these and recognize the shapes with python. For example I would like the following representation in Python:

```
result = [('red_circle', 'green_square'), ('green_square', 'green_square'), ('blue_circle', 'red_circle')]
```

In effect I want the ones in the same column to be in a tuple, so I know they are simultaneous.

Can I do this with tensorflow?

Comment: Using TF is superfluoust. Opencv or even PIL is sufficient.

Comment: @AlexAlex Ok, can you give me a pointer about which part of OpenCV to use?

Comment: InRange() in HSV for color detection, 
connectedComponentsWithStats for shape detection (Area/minAreaRect ratio)

Comment: @AlexAlex Ok, what if I have images of the buttons and I want to detect if these are in images of the whole band?

Comment: cv2.matchTemplate()

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html

Comment: @AlexAlex Do you think it will be enough to just use matchTemplate? Won't I have to train a model? These are relatively simple shapes, but the lightning might be different etc.